# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, excepciones, jtable, index

Necesitaría ayuda para resolver este error, teóricamente debería funcionar ya que la tabla muestra que tiene registros ingresados (cuando pulso el botón para cargar los mismos), pero el error me devuelve que el array está vacío. Agradecería si alguien pudiera darme la solución. Considero que el error se encuentra en el método actualizarDatos(), pero según mi criterio el mismo debería funcionar correctamente. También dejo el método que utilizo para cargar la tabla, por si consideran que el error se encuentra allí (aunque no lo creo).

```
    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Filtrar");
    btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement st=DatabaseManager.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM RECLAMO WHERE ESTADO=? AND USUARIO=?");
                String estado = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                String usuariodesdelogin = textField.getText();
                st.setString(1, estado);
                st.setString(2, usuariodesdelogin);
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();


                int numColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();
                
                DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
                table.setModel(modelo);

                for(int i=1; i<=numColumnas; i++) {
                    modelo.addColumn(rsMd.getColumnLabel(i));
                }

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Object [] fila = new Object[numColumnas];

                    for(int y=0; y<numColumnas; y++) {
                        fila [y]=rs.getObject(y+1);
                    }

                    modelo.addRow(fila);
                    
                    AutoSizeColumnas aSc = new AutoSizeColumnas();
                    aSc.resizeColumnWidth(table);
                    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
                    
                }
                
                comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

            }catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });

public void actualizarDatos() {
    int fila = table.getSelectedRow();
    
    int id = Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
    String titulo = table.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString();
    String descripcion = table.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString();
    String fecha_reclamo = table.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString();
    String hora = table.getValueAt(fila, 4).toString();
    String nombre_evento = table.getValueAt(fila, 5).toString();
    String nombre_actividad = table.getValueAt(fila, 6).toString();
    int semestre = Integer.parseInt(this.table.getValueAt(fila, 7).toString());
    String fecha_actividad = table.getValueAt(fila, 8).toString();
    String docente = table.getValueAt(fila, 9).toString();
    int creditos  = Integer.parseInt(this.table.getValueAt(fila, 10).toString());
    String usuario = table.getValueAt(fila, 11).toString();
    String estado = table.getValueAt(fila, 12).toString();
    
    try {
        PreparedStatement actu = DatabaseManager.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE RECLAMO SET TITULO='"+titulo+"', DESCRIPCION='"+descripcion+"', FECHA_RECLAMO='"+fecha_reclamo+"', HORA='"+hora+"', "
                + "NOMBRE_EVENTO='"+nombre_evento+"', NOMBRE_ACTIVIDAD='"+nombre_actividad+"', SEMESTRE='"+semestre+"', FECHA_ACTIVIDAD='"+fecha_actividad+"', DOCENTE='"+docente+"', CREDITOS='"+creditos+"', USUARIO='"+usuario+"', ESTADO='"+estado+"' "
                        + "WHERE ID_RECLAMO='"+id+"'");
        actu.executeUpdate();
        
    
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo actualizar");
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Hola @Santiago Marrero, en algún lugar, le estás pidiendo un dato a un array vacio, con lo que nos muestras es difícil saber cual es, tendrías que fijarte la linea que arroja la excepción, ver cual es el array vacio, y luego ver porque está vacio.

Comment: Creo que tu problema está aquí: `fila [y]=rs.getObject(y+1);`, no deberías aumentar a `y` en ese punto, pues `y` irá aumentando en la iteracción del bucle al poner `y++`, por tanto, debes ponerlo así: **`fila [y]=rs.getObject(y);`**

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que definitivamente la consulta no obtiene resultados, debes verificar primeramente que el valor del combobox (`(String)comboBox.getSelectedItem()`) corresponda a un valor de `ESTADO` y el valor del textField (`textField.getText()`) corresponda a un `USUARIO` en tu tabla `RECLAMO` de otra forma no obtendrás resultados y obtendrás el error.

Debes validar para que este problema no ocurra en tu código.

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Filtrar");
btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement st=DatabaseManager.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM RECLAMO WHERE ESTADO=? AND USUARIO=?");
            String estado = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            String usuariodesdelogin = textField.getText();
            st.setString(1, estado);
            st.setString(2, usuariodesdelogin);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();


            int numColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();
            
            if(numColumnas > 0){ //*Existe información.

               DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
               table.setModel(modelo);

               for(int i=1; i<=numColumnas; i++) {
                   modelo.addColumn(rsMd.getColumnLabel(i));
               }

               while (rs.next()) {
                   Object [] fila = new Object[numColumnas];

                   for(int y=0; y<numColumnas; y++) {
                       fila [y]=rs.getObject(y+1);
                   }

                   modelo.addRow(fila);
                
                   AutoSizeColumnas aSc = new AutoSizeColumnas();
                   aSc.resizeColumnWidth(table);
                   table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
                
               }
            
               comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

              }else{//*No existe información.
                 System.out.println("No se obtuvo información...");
              }

        }catch (SQLException e1) {
            //e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
});
```